# process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, io

I am using ASP.NET Webforms with C#. On one page I click submit to create a file on the server.

```
File.Create(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LandingPages"])
            + landingPage.FriendlyName);
```

This works fine and creates the file as expected. However, after it does this it redirects to another page, which reads the file that was just created.

```
var landingPageContent 
       = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LandingPages"]) 
                          + landingPage.FriendlyName);
```

That's when I get this error.

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\code\Content\CMS\LandingPages\Test2' because it is being used by another process.

If I restart IIS then the process releases the file and I can load that page and read the file just fine. Is there something I need to do after `File.Create` in order to close the file before the redirect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you close the stream returned by `File.Create`? The name is a bit confusing (it comes all the way from the bowels of WinAPI), but it creates a file *and* opens it for writing for you.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice that it returned a stream. Thanks much! Will accept when I can :)

Answer (score 7):

File.Create returns Filstream, try this:

```
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(...)){}
```

or shorter:

```
File.Create(...).Dispose();
```

Comment: This works as well. After Matti's answer I found it easier to do `File.Create(.....).Dispose();`. Thank you cichy.

Answer (score 4):

try replacing:

```
File.Create(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LandingPages"]) + landingPage.FriendlyName);
```

with:

```
using(File.Create(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LandingPages"]) + landingPage.FriendlyName))
{}
```

so the file handle is immedately disposed/released

Answer (score 3):

Just close it:

```
var fileStream = File.Create(...);
fileStream.Close();
```

If you are doing something with created file it would be better wrapping this logic by `using` block which finally would close a handle:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(...))
{
   // logic
}
```