# C#: Access denied on deleting file

Tags: c#

I have a c# application to merge more than one TIFF file. After merging the files, i am saving it to some other location,and deleting the original TIFF(image file). But it's giving an error `"The process cannot access the file 'D:\A\Merged.tif' because it is being used by another process."`

i am also use GC.collect() method to free the resources...

Kindly help, How to delete such files?

```
 int mergeTiffPages(string filepath,string[] path)
    {
        string[] sa = path;
        ImageCodecInfo info = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                info = ice;
        Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
        EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
        Bitmap pages = null;
        int frame = 0;
        foreach (string s in sa){
            if (frame == 0){
                pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
                //save the first frame
                pages.Save(filepath, info, ep);
            }
            else{
                //save the intermediate frames
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
                pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
            }
            if (frame == sa.Length - 1)
            {
                //flush and close.
                ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                pages.SaveAdd(ep);
            }
            frame++;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are merging the file? Are you closing the file when you are done merging?

Comment: You will keep getting downvotes my friend until you show some code.

Comment: Show relevant code. Do research (i.e. paste your exception message in your favourite web search engine). See for example [process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006568/process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process).

Comment: Voted up , being new to SO. But in future post question with detail and some piece of code.

Comment: string[] sa = path;
            ImageCodecInfo info = null;
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
                if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                    info = ice;
            Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
            EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
            Bitmap pages = null;
            int frame = 0;

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code with `Using {}` Blocks if possible. Here is a sample code for reading files using `Using`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      using (TextWriter w = File.CreateText("log.txt")) {
         w.WriteLine("This is line one");
         w.WriteLine("This is line two");
      }
      using (TextReader r = File.OpenText("log.txt")) {
         string s;
         while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @HirenRaiyani This is just for help. Its not the actual piece of code.

Comment: I put the code in my question please show and give me a answer

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not closing image files properly. That might be the reason for getting this exception. Try code below

```
foreach (string s in sa){
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
       continue;
    }

    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(s, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (frame == 0){
            pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(fileStream);
            //save the first frame
        }
        else{
            //save the intermediate frames
        }
        if (frame == sa.Length - 1)
        {
            //flush and close.
        }
        frame++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry,its throw outofmemory exception

Comment: What is the size of the TIFF file?

Comment: File Size is 10 to 15 KB but its also be a big but in this example i m use 10 to 15 kb file.

Comment: check the code now. Some of your string might have invalid file path. I am just checking if they are null or empty.

Comment: No, when frame=1 then else part in control go and when executing   Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s); on this line error occured OutOfMemoryException was Unhandled